# How to use Shuffle.c index mode for complex numbers

Tags: matlab, shuffle

I want to shuffle a 3d array on the third dimension using [Shuffle.c](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27076-shuffle).
Till now I have used `Shuffle(arr,3)` with great performance. Now I try to do the same, but with array of Complex numbers and get this Error:

```
*** Shuffle[mex]: Use index mode for complex input!
```

I haven't found the proper way to use index mode.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you verify the better performance for you input sizes? For 3D matrices shuffling one dimensions, you are better off not using the MEX function with the above mentioned syntax. It forces MATLAB to copy the whole matrix to mex and back. For comparison:

```
arr=rand(100,100,100);
t.mexshuffle=timeit(@()(Shuffle(arr,3)));
t.randperm=timeit(@()arr(:,:,randperm(size(arr,3))));
t.mexindexshuffle=timeit(@()arr(:,:,Shuffle(size(arr,3),'index')));
```

The results are:

```
  struct with fields:

         mexshuffle: 0.0183
           randperm: 0.0038
    mexindexshuffle: 0.0037
```

It does not really matter if you use `Shuffle` with the index option or `randperm`, but directly using `Shuffle` is slower. Nice side-effect, the later two options support complex numbers.

Above code might be a bit hard to read, here a cleaner version of the suggested solution:

```
P=randperm(size(arr,3)); % Permutation vector, use whichever generator you prefer.
%P=Shuffle(size(arr,3),'index');
arr_out=arr(:,:,P);
```